# Admin grid back button being added twice

Tags: magento-1, grid

See example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2hpd.png]

In `My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Audit_Productnoimage` I have

```
<?php

class My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Audit_Productnoimage
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container
{
    /**
     * Add buttons
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->addButton('back', array(
            'label'   => $this->__('Back'),
            'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/')}')",
            'class'   => 'back'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Header text getter
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        return $this->__('Products Without Images');
    }

    /**
     * Grid contents getter
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to track down where the second `Back` button is coming from but I can't figure it out.  For some reason it's being returned in the `getChildHtml()` above but before the `grid.phtml` content.  Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Check this file for the back button, my guess is that it is already in the code of this file

Comment: It is not, hence it being outside of the template hint, which is what makes this one weird/hard to track down.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need this, so just remove it.

```
   $this->addButton('back', array(
        'label'   => $this->__('Back'),
        'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/')}')",
        'class'   => 'back'
    ));
```

Since this will be called automatically.

Check this file: `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container.php`

> ```
> protected function _addBackButton()
>     {
>         $this->_addButton('back', array(
>             'label'     => $this->getBackButtonLabel(),
>             'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getBackUrl() .'\')',
>             'class'     => 'back',
>         ));
>     }
> ```

However, if you do want to replace the button url may be then just add this

```
$this->_removeButton('back');
$this->addButton('back_custom', array(
        'label'   => $this->__('Back'),
        'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/')}')",
        'class'   => 'back'
    ));
```

Here we are removing default back button and adding our own.